# flutter will not run coming back with Build failed with an exception. error

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, flutter-test, gradle-kotlin-dsl

i just started on flutter i am just a beginner at it. every time I hit run this error occurs

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM N950F in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10.

Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.6.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.10.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.6.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.10.pom'.
               > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.232.80.215] failed: Read timed out
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.32.
     Required by:
```

and keeps running over and over

could not find an answer

Comment: Please type in terminal: flutter doctor -v  then add the results in your question